# Is there a way to wrap an AngularJS component into a web component using Angular Element?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-elements

We currently have a hybrid application that consists of AngularJS and Angular 9. We are in the process of trying to get the entire application over to Angular 9 but are running into some difficulties. We are currently using ngUpgrade to help us but it seems like this will not be scalable. We are trying to leverage Angular Elements and use web components to help. Is there a way to wrap AngularJS components into Angular Elements to use in Angular 9 components? If so, are there any resources you can point me to? Please?